# In Typescript 4.9, there is an error when trying to create a map containing sets of generic functions when using an Enum as key

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

This code used to work on Typescript 4.8

```
enum MyEnum {
  A = 'my-a',
  B = 'my-b',
}

type MyEnumToObjectMap = {
  [MyEnum.A]: {
    a: string;
  };
  [MyEnum.B]: {
    b: string;
  };
};

type MyGenericFunction<T extends MyEnum> = (data: MyEnumToObjectMap[T])=>void

type Functions = {
  [key in MyEnum]: Set<MyGenericFunction<key>>;
};

// Build the map
const map = {} as Functions;
for (const value of Object.values(MyEnum)) {
  map[value] = new Set<MyGenericFunction<typeof value>>();
}
console.log(map);
```

I want to create a map using `MyEnum` values as the keys. For each key, there is a Set of functions. The functions are generic and depend on the enum values

In Typescript 4.9, I'm getting:

> S2322: Type 'Set<MyGenericFunction>' is not assignable to type 'Set<MyGenericFunction<MyEnum.A>> & Set<MyGenericFunction<MyEnum.B>>'.   Types of property 'add' are incompatible.     Type '(value: MyGenericFunction) => Set<MyGenericFunction>' is not assignable to type '((value: MyGenericFunction<MyEnum.A>) => Set<MyGenericFunction<MyEnum.A>> & Set<MyGenericFunction<MyEnum.B>>) & ((value: MyGenericFunction<...>) => Set<...> & Set<...>)'.       Type '(value: MyGenericFunction) => Set<MyGenericFunction>' is not assignable to type '(value: MyGenericFunction<MyEnum.A>) => Set<MyGenericFunction<MyEnum.A>> & Set<MyGenericFunction<MyEnum.B>>'.         Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.           Types of parameters 'data' and 'data' are incompatible.             Type '{ a: string; } | { b: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ a: string; }'.               Property 'a' is missing in type '{ b: string; }' but required in type '{ a: string; }'.

Why is this not working in Typescript 4.9?

Comment: Okay, so this changed between [2022-10-13](https://tsplay.dev/NVb2ZN) and [2022-10-14](https://tsplay.dev/WoAOaN), and the only merged PR I see that should even remotely affect this is [ms/TS#51140](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/51140). Looks like intersections of covariant types (with bivariant methods) are no longer assignable from the corresponding union type.  Not sure if this is a bug or a limitation, but I'll probably report it and see what they say.  Does this constitute an answer to your question if I write it up or am I missing something?

Comment: I have reported [microsoft/TypeScript#51620](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51620) and will see how it goes.  Please let me know if I shouldn't write up an answer for some reason.

Comment: Not sure if this is actually the cause, but if you write an answer I'll mark it unless there is a better one!

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer when I get a chance, although I might wait until ms/TS#51620 is triaged so I'm sure what's going on.